# After compiling a script with py2exe, program does not launch

Tags: python, compilation

After compiling a program with py2exe, It does not launch, the only thing that appears is a command prompt quickly flashing on the screen (Figure 1)

Figure 1:
https://gyazo.com/088bf4ad71d11d8025ceffb1e3fa67d5

This is my py2exe setup script:
https://gyazo.com/884368e712a402101f3ed5549799e826

All dependencies (like pictures and other things) where added in the folder before I opened it.

EDIT: Sample code

```
import subprocess
import os
import platform
import sys
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

menu=Tk()
menu.wm_title("xCheat")

def reset():

    img=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("mcomain.png"))
    imglabel=Label(menu, image=img).grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=2)

    test3=Label(text="Coded By Jmilicev",fg="black",font="Arial 10")
    test3.grid(row=12,column=0,columnspan=2)
    test3.grid(sticky="WE")

    resource_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'resources');

    def Button1():
        os.startfile(os.path.join(resource_dir, 'LastActivityViewer.exe'))

    def Button2():
        os.startfile(os.path.join(resource_dir, 'pho.exe'))

    def Button3():
        os.startfile(os.path.join(resource_dir, 'procexp.exe'))

    def Button4():
        os.startfile(os.path.join(resource_dir, 'IJ.exe'))

    def Button5():
        os.startfile(os.path.join(resource_dir, 'Br.exe'))

    def Button22():
        os.startfile(os.path.join(resource_dir, 'sky.bat'))

    def Programs():

        b1=Button(text="Last Activity Viewer",fg="red",bg="black",command=Button1)
        b1.grid(row=1,column=0)
        b1.grid(sticky="WE,NS")
        b1.config(height=4,width=0)

        b2=Button(text="Process Hacker",fg="red",bg="black",command=Button2)
        b2.grid(row=1,column=1)
        b2.grid(sticky="WE,NS")
        b2.config(height=4,width=0)

        b3=Button(text="Process Explorer",fg="red",bg="black",command=Button3)
        b3.grid(row=2,column=0)
        b3.grid(sticky="WE,NS")
        b3.config(height=4,width=0)

        b14=Button(text="Search Everything",fg="red",bg="black",command=Button14)
        b14.grid(row=2,column=1)
        b14.grid(sticky="WE,NS")
        b14.config(height=4,width=0)


    menu.mainloop()

reset()
```

Comment: Could you actually share the code? Pretty sure because something is erroring out or your program executes and closes immediately,

Comment: program itself works completely fine... added it in though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be many things, an error report will help with determining the cause.

Run the program in a command prompt and share the output, please.

A good alternative to py2exe is cx_freeze, some example code:

```
# run this code as: compile.py
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("xCheat.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="xCheat",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["LIBRARY_NAME",],
                           "include_files":[]}},  # accepts directory names
    executables = executables

)
```

Comment: No error is produced, thats all i get ...https://gyazo.com/08b052a92c1d0e3bcb7f2462f4f056b0

Comment: Can you share the compilation output

edit: I can recommend cx_freeze, I've had trouble in the past with py2exe and haven't been able to resolve it. cx_freeze is recommendable as well; I'll be editing my answer with recommended code

Comment: Hm... could you help me converter it with cx_freeze? i believe i have it installed already... my python script is called xCheat.py, Also, you can install extra files like changelogs and such with cx_freeze right? I have a few programs that need to be added in there, specifically a "resource" folder and a png named "mcomain"

Comment: take a look at the code in my answer, I think it should work

Comment: gives me a error despite it being in the correct folder https://gyazo.com/3c3636f73de0232184b7c374a98f1924

Comment: I think you're in the wrong directory, this error indicates Python can't find the compile script

Comment: Thats what I though as well, I think its broken... https://gyazo.com/b11f1faa0469570a34f6a9332a97ffd9 its very visibly in the correct directory.

Comment: that's strange; try opening within Explorer.
maybe share
> python -v

Comment: I changed the name and it executed, I got this error https://gyazo.com/f60151ed4d99c326520f6eb3c500e4bd

Comment: This can be due to file permissions or 64-bit, 32-bit problems

Try installing wx_freeze again, and try to run in a admin command prompt

Comment: Finally compiled (I know) Then, Just when i thought it was done... I get this https://gyazo.com/ddd0378c3b2ee3c685239ab9ad0c5441, Is there any requirements that i need in my code for it to work properly? It works completely fine when I launch it from IDLE...

Comment: Fixed it! thank you for all your help! really do appreciate it :)